# How to change desktop resoloution on Windows Server 2016 over rtp?

Tags: windows-server-2016

My desktop resoloution is currently locked to a horrific 1080 X 520 and I am unable to change it because I get the error,"the display settings cant be changed from a remote session", And there is no way for me to access the server besides a remote connection. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you or not but still give it a try [to this.](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/smart-resizing.html)

Comment: This works while connected with this service, but when going to another, it just defaults back, and to my knowledge there is no way to set it permanently in my conditions.